# cs-cart extending core controllers - debugging

Tags: php, debugging, cs-cart

I'm trying to modify the user's address right after registration.

When you create a new user, The address needs to be modified and a trailing string needs to be added, such as this : ####.

I've created an addon, added the path /controllers/frontend/profiles.post.php, 
I've attached to the `$mode == 'add'` , That's where I'm stuck.

How can I know which variables are available to me, It seems there's no way to debug, var_dump or echo. nothing seems to work.

The file is executing because if I type some broken syntax the server returns `500 internal error`,

So my main question :
**How can you debug at all any CS-cart addon?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick,

To find out what variables do you have you can use fn_print_r($_REQUEST)
where 
fn_print_r - good looking cs-cart wrapper of print_r

Actually the variables from profiles.php are not available in profiles.post.php because these are different variable scopes.

So most probably the only variables you will have is global PHP like $_REQUEST $_SERVER etc..

Take a look at discussion or bestsellers add-on - they have products.post.php controllers which work absolutly the same ways a profiles.post.php and any other post controllers.

Comment: Hey ilya, so even though this runs after profiles php, it doesnt get the same variables? I guess regular hooks are run inside the function scope. Thanks!

Comment: Patrick, do not mix up hooks & post/pre controllers.
Hooks accept the parameters you send to it.
Post/Pre controllers does not have any variables. So you need to use either global variables, Registry on Constants.

Comment: Thanks Ilya, It felt a bit starnge having a POST and PRE controller get no params, but I guess that's how it was written :) thanks alot!